# What are the changelogs of Gazebo 7.16.0 recently released?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

On Ubuntu 16.04, up until one week ago the `gazebo` version released on the PPA below was the `7.15.0`

```
echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list

wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | apt-key add -
```

Today when installing gazebo again, the version installed was `7.16.0`.

I couldn't find the changelog of this version on https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Changelog.md

Does anybody know what changed from version `7.15.0` to `7.16.0`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23718/what-are-the-changelogs-of-gazebo-7.16.0-recently-released?/) by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok, I found the answer looking directly on the `gazebo7` branch:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo7/Changelog.md

---

Gazebo 7.16.0 (2019-09-04)

1. VariableGearboxPlugin: use splines to support arbitrary smooth input-output gearbox profiles

   [Pull request 3073](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/3073)
2. Backport Camera PreRender and PostRender events

   [Pull request 3119](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/3119)

---

Originally posted by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) with karma: 11 on 2019-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-09-06**:
Did you meant to include the link to the changelog?

**Comment by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on 2019-09-06**:
Thanks @kumpakri , now I put the correct link to the changelog.